# Perform action on certain Y coordinate

Tags: android, coordinates

I'm trying to make a view invisible when it's dragged to a certain Y coordinate on the screen. 
This is what I got now:

```
private final class dragTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                ContentFrameLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (ContentFrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                trash_image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                trash_image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                ContentFrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ContentFrameLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                if(v.getY() > trash_image.getY()){
                    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                break;
        }
        contentView.invalidate();
        return true;



    }

}
```

So basically what I've tried here is simply an if statement to check if the Y position of the view has "passed" that of another ImageView placed on the upper part of the screen. This however result in becoming invisible as soon as I touch the view to be dragged, no matter where on the screen it's located. So it's far from accurate, or wrong all together.

Comment: When a view is being dragged, the layout is constantly changing, meaning that the x,y coords of a view will be a value, then 0, then a new value. In my program, my issue was that the raw pixel values do not consider the Screen density `SCREEN_DENSITY = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;`, then using `(int) (event.getRawX() / SCREEN_DENSITY)` made those values "correct". Note that you must compare values in the same "scope", so, get the raw pixel, as well as the `View.getLocationOnScreen()`

Comment: @Bonatti there seem to be a lot more to it than I thought then. Could you perhaps write out an answer displaying how you did it, so I may mark it ass correct?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I can do a mockup of what I did, since is a program that is owned by my company, and not me. I will try to post a way for resolution.

Comment: @Bonatti I understand. Thank you, I just need some general pseudo code so I can see the basics and how to apply them.

Comment: What I used, uses "less screen refreshes" (english is not my native language) then dragging a shadow view (`View.DragShadowBuilder()`). So I went ahead and build the layout as needed. I have a Framelayout and isnde, the moveable parts (its a program necessity that a child does not move "out" of its parent, thats what MyObject is used for.). If you still want some help, just reply here.

Comment: @Bonatti So when I then want to check if the movable view is "overlapping" a certain point, I would use that Integer generated by "event.getRawY() / SCREEN_DENSITY" to get the position of the movable view? And then check it against some value. Correct?

Comment: No. the way I made it, the layout remains. Once a change is made (the function movFrame happens), then you now have a new layout. Now you can check. Otherwise, what you may want to do is get the "limit view" original position, and then, always check the new "moving" view against that value. If you check the "limit view" constantly, then you may check while it is not ready (and thus comparing it as if it were 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in comment, a suggestion (do note I had to change it, since this is for a client program, so I didnt test it again):

> First, discover SCREEN_DENSITY

```
private static float SCREEN_DENSITY = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

> The onTouch function:

```
public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
      mainFinger = new Point(
         (int) (event.getRawX() / SCREEN_DENSITY),
         (int) (event.getRawY() / SCREEN_DENSITY)
      );
         break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
      movFrame(
         (FrameLayout) v,
         (int) (event.getRawX() / SCREEN_DENSITY),
         (int) (event.getRawY() / SCREEN_DENSITY)
      );
}
```

> movFrame function:

```
private void movFrame(FrameLayout v, int movX, int movY) {
    MyObject p = (MyObject ) v.getTag();
    int[] x, y, h, w;
    x = p.x;
    y = p.y;
    h = p.h;
    w = p.w;
    x = p.x + movX - mainFinger.x;
    mainFinger.x = movX;
    if (x + w > p.parent.w) {
        x = p.parent.w - w;
    }
    if (x < 0) {
        x = 0;
    }
    y = p.y + movY - mainFinger.y;
    mainFinger.y = movY;
    if (y + h > p.parent.h) {
        y = p.parent.h - h;
    }
    if (y < 0) {
        y = 0;
    }
    p.updateMyObject(x, y, h, w);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            (int) ((p.w * SCREEN_DENSITY) + 0.5),
            (int) ((p.h * SCREEN_DENSITY) + 0.5)
    );
    params.leftMargin = (int) ((p.x * SCREEN_DENSITY) + 0.5);
    params.topMargin = (int) ((p.y * SCREEN_DENSITY) + 0.5);
    v.setLayoutParams(params);
}
```